# dplyr unnest() not working for large comma separated data

Tags: r, dplyr, unnest

Trying to use dplyr's unnest function to split apart a large character data set separated by commas.  The data set has the form:

```
id                                     keywords
 835a24fe-c276-9824-0f4d-35fc81319cca  Analytics,Artificial Intelligence,Big Data,Health Care
```

I want to create a table that has the "id" in column one and each of the "keywords" in a separate column with the same "id"

I'm using the code:

```
CB_keyword <- tibble(id=organizations$uuid[organizations$uuid %in% org_uuid ] , 
                     keyword=organizations$category_list[organizations$uuid %in% org_uuid]) %>% unnest(keyword, names_sep = ",")
```

The %in% code is selecting "id" and "keyword" info from another table ... and it is doing this correctly.  The piping to unnest seems to do nothing.  The tibble remains unchanged except that the column name is now "keyword,keyword" instead of "keyword", but the data is the same as if the unnest command is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `keywords` is a string column, use `separate_rows` instead of `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    separate_rows(keywords, sep=",\\s*")
```

Comment: This worked .. thank you!